# Can a function​ $f:A\to B$ exist with $A\subset B$?

Tags: functions

Define a function $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$. I am talking about continuous functions just for a note.

1. Can we have a smaller domain? Like, $A\in [a,b]$ where $$a>>>-\infty$$ $$b<<<+\infty$$
2. When the codomain is $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ (but not a proper subset) and $A\in \mathbb{R}$, we may have possible functions like $\sin(x)$ where definitely $x$ is in radians. I don't know anything apart from trigonometric functions that satisfy this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$. With $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2$. 
Not every element from $B$ has to be maped onto. That is a property which surjective functions have. Not every function has to be surjective.

Edit: You can give an example which is continuous easily for $B=\mathbb{R}$ too. Just consider $f:[1,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $x\mapsto x$.

Answer (score 1):

Any function $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ can have its domain "artificially" restricted. Likewise, if $f$ is not surjective, then its codomain can be "artificially" restricted until it is surjective.

Most functions you see in a calculus class are implicitly defined such that its domain is "as big as possible". One example of a function whose domain/codomain are "naturally" not all of $\mathbb R$ is the continuous function $f\colon [3, 7] \to [0, 2]$ defined by:
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{(x - 3)(7 - x)} 
$$